# Sphinx & node.js client

Tags: node.js, sphinx

Ok, Sphinx seems to be the stupidest app out there.

First off, the command

```
search "test"
```

Never works, and is a common problem, giving the following error:

```
index 'test1': search error: .
```

Then, if I use the node.js client for it, I get the error:

```
Error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
Connection ERROR: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
Connected, sending query
RESULTS: undefined
closed
Connection ERROR: Error: The socket has closed due to an unknown error
```

Fine, I say. Let's check the log. NOTHING, just this:

```
[Tue Sep 11 14:38:54.406 2012] [ 3769] accepting connections
```

Anyone who had similar issues?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Do you perhaps have a firewall blocking access to what ever port you have searchd running on?

Have you tried test.php or test.py - as opposed to using "search"